# Jquery $("#").html(data) vulnerable to XSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

```
$.get("/Controller/ActionMethod", function (data) {
    $("#id").html(data);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Highlighted line has vulnerability finding in security scan. Data object has some hyperlinks to redirect other pages. So `$("#id").text(data);` will not satisfy our requirement.

Tried this but not working.

```
var X = data.replace(`/&/g`, "`&amp;`").replace(`/</g`, "`&lt;`").replace(`/>/g`, "`&gt;`");

$("#id").html(X);
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you edit the question and apply better formatting?

Comment: Who is giving you this feedback? What is the requirement?

Comment: `.text()` is ***absolutely*** the correct way to go here. It's safe from XSS. Any roll your own solution is very likely vulnerable. An alternative would be to accept an *extremely* limited set of HTML and clean up anything that doesn't match. It's even better if you don't get any HTML but instead some intermediary code (e.g., Markdown) that then gets *safely* transformed into HTML. Whitelisting always beats blacklisting.